# settimeout jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to do the following in jquery:

for a period total of 90 seconds:

each 5 seconds, do an ajax call on a webpage, get the result. 
if the result = 1, output a "success" message to the screen.
if the result = 0, wait for another 5 seconds.

repeat the above steps until 90 seconds has passed.

how can I do the above? I am guessing setTimeout can help, but how I configure that to make it work for my task?

I tried doing:

```
   var id = setInterval(function()
   {
    $.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
         $('.result').html(data);

      });
   }, 5000);
```

but I am not sure how to stop this after 90 seconds, or how to stop setInteval if test.php returns a 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clearInterval(id);
```

Run this after 90 seconds

See Docs: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)